# File sending from browser to a server which is not a web server

Tags: php, security, file-transfer

I want to send a file from my browser to a server which is not the server on which the site is hosted.The problem is the another server is not a web server. 
Is it programmatically possible to send a file to different server without the involvement of host server? I do not want copy of the file I am uploading on my hosting server.

Sorry for not being clear on the first go. I hope this makes sense.

Note: I have the IP address of server. Implementation has to be done in a secure way.

Comment: That does not make any sense. Also, you should start by yourself and post back here when you have specific problems, this is too broad.

Comment: @jeroen I started to implement but I could not find any way. I was trying to do it with soap server but i do not want file to be saved on web server but i want it to be sent directly to another remote server.

Comment: @MikeW Thanks a lot for drawing my attention. it was typo error. I hope this make sense

Comment: Your browser is built to run web services. If this 'other server' is not running web services then your browser will have trouble talking to it. Your web server is potentially more flexible and, if you know which protocols are available on your 'other server', could possibly transfer the file for you. You'd have to upload to your web server and have that server pass the file on. Since you've given no details of the 'other server', I can't say how, or even if that's actually possible.

Comment: @MikeW Thanks Mike. The other server is a storage server, just for storing extra data. I can configure it the way i want.

Comment: You seem to be new to SO, so just a hint that three of us have already voted to reopen your question. In my opinion, you could improve your question even further if you have an idea what the file transfer protocol of your other (non-web) server could be.

Comment: @s.bandara. Thanks for that. I thought of FTP but we do not want any file transfer protocol to be installed on the storage server. My be socket would work. I am looking for the alternatives now.

Comment: "Socket" is a very low level part of networking. You need a protocol to run over the top of sockets. Also, you need to define "secure", what does secure mean for you? Are you trying to limit who can upload? Are you trying to encrypt data enroute so it can't be spied up on? Something else?

Comment: Would FTP be an option?

Comment: @GeoffreyBurdett — The OP rejected FTP in the previous comment … although on rather odd grounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for valuable suggestions. I am opting for bit weird way but it seems the only feasible solution considering the current requirements of the project.

I am planning to install lite version of web server and php on the external server which can accept uploaded files through browser.

Our team has worked out this is the best solution we can consider as of now.

Thanks again to all for their suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a signed application to handle the upload.**

One of the fundamental rules of browser sandboxing is that you don't let the browser communicate to a server other than the one which provided the website.  This has been a rule for quite some time, and is done for security reasons.

The only way I know of to bypass this restriction is to use a signed application.  This is possible in several languages including at least Flash and Java.  Once you've signed your application with an authoritative source, then you can specify that your application is known to communicate with a third-party server and should be trusted to do so.  The process of doing this will be different depending on the technology you choose.

The server to which you are sending the file needs to allow some sort of protocol in order to accept the file.  You do not specify what that is, but these languages should be more than sufficient to implement whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks Erick.. Do you mean creating Java applet and authorizing it?

Comment: Yes, that's one way.  Once it's signed, it can operate outside of the browser sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

given that you have the necessary authentication of the secondary server you can
i'll explain using ftp, but there can be other socket related ways

1) upload the file to your server as usual, using $_FILE

2) use the [ftp](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) class in php to transfer the file to the remote host

Comment: This was the first way I think of but you know we would be creating an extra copy of a file on a server which we do not want because of security reasons.

Comment: well any other solution would involve cross domain authoring which would have issues later

Answer (score 0):

This is done all the time with Firefox plugins, (youtube etc.).  Does it have to be driven from your page source ? How stealthily do you want to do this ?
The other server should use a common protocol, SSH or ftp or NFS or CIFS.

In any case the user is going to have to agree with the plugin or the applet or a third party service (think punkbuster) running in the background.

BF4 runs in a browser window via a plugin and routinely sends data to servers other than the game server.